# TypeError: Can not convert a NoneType into a Tensor or Operation -- Error believe related to converting to graph

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

Below find my model:

```
class CustomModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, model1, model2, model3, model4):
        super(deep_and_wide, self).__init__()
        self.model1 = model1
        self.model2 = model2
        self.model3 = model3
        self.model4 = model4

    def call(self, inputs):
        x1 = self.mode1([inputs["a"], inputs["b"]])
        x2 = self.model2([inputs["a"], inputs["b"]])
        x3 = self.model3([inputs["a"], inputs["b"]])
        x4 = self.model4([inputs["a"], inputs["b"]])
        x = Concatenate()([x1, x2, x3])
        x = TimeDistributed(Dense(2))(x)

        x = Add()([x, x4])
        x_fc = Dense(1)(x)
        x_ec = Dense(1)(x)

        return x_fc, x_ec


    def train_step(self, data):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            data = data_adapter.expand_1d(data)
            batch_inputs, batch_outputs, sample_weight= data_adapter.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(data)

            y_true_fc, y_true_ec = batch_outputs["y_fc"], batch_outputs["y_ec"]
            y_pred_fc, y_pred_ec = self(batch_inputs, training=True)
            loss_fc = self.compiled_loss(y_true_fc, y_pred_fc)
            loss_ec = self.compiled_loss(y_true_ec, y_pred_ec)
        print("here")
        trainable_variables = self.trainable_variables
        print("here")
        gradients = tape.gradient([loss_fc, loss_ec], trainable_variables)
        print("here")
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_variables))
        print("here")
```

And below is my custom loss

```
class CustomLoss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, mask=True, alpha=1, beta=1, gamma=1, dtype=tf.float64):
        super(CustomLoss, self).__init__(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
        self.mask = mask
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.dtype = dtype

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred, mask):
            y_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, mask)
            y_pred = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, mask)
            return tf.keras.losses.MSE(y_true, y_pred)

        self.mask = tf.not_equal(y_true, 0.)

        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, self.dtype)
        y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, self.dtype)

        y_pred = tf.multiply(y_pred, tf.cast(self.mask, dtype=self.dtype))
        y_pred_cum = tf.math.cumsum(y_pred, axis=1)
        y_pred_cum = tf.multiply(y_pred_cum, tf.cast(self.mask, dtype=self.dtype))

        y_true_cum = tf.math.cumsum(y_true, axis=1)
        y_true_cum = tf.multiply(y_true_cum, tf.cast(self.mask, dtype=self.dtype))

        loss_value = self.alpha * loss_fn(y_true, y_pred, self.mask) + \
                     self.gamma * loss_fn(y_true_cum, y_pred_cum, self.mask)

        return loss_value
```

And then finally:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam() 
loss = CustomLoss()
model.compile(optimizer, loss) 
model.fit(train_data, epochs=5, validation_data=val_data)
```

My data inputs are of size (sequence length, feature length) where sequence length is variable hence I am using `tf.data.experimental.bucket_by_sequence_length` to pad to max sequence length of the batch (as opposed to batch to max sequence length). All in all, my train and val data are tf.data.Datasets each created using `tf.data.experimental.bucket_by_sequence_length` where each batch is of size (None, None, feature length).

When I run the above code, I get the following errors and cannot seem to understand where I am going wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 75, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1100, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 871, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 725, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3196, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 977, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
TypeError: in user code:
    C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:790 run_step  **
        with ops.control_dependencies(_minimum_control_deps(outputs)):
    C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:5359 control_dependencies
        return get_default_graph().control_dependencies(control_inputs)
    C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py:362 control_dependencies
        return super(FuncGraph, self).control_dependencies(filtered_control_inputs)
    C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:4815 control_dependencies
        c = self.as_graph_element(c)
    C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:3726 as_graph_element
        return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
    C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\tf_recsys\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:3814 _as_graph_element_locked
        raise TypeError("Can not convert a %s into a %s." %
    TypeError: Can not convert a NoneType into a Tensor or Operation.
```

The four print statements inserted in the `train_step` function above are printed.

Answer (score 2):

This NoneType refers to the returned value of the custom train_step, when using a custom train_step you should return something that can be converted into a tensor so that the minimum control dependencies can process it, typically, the loss value as {"loss": loss_value} and potentially some other metrics, or at least an empty dict {}.